# asp.net publishing not deploiying correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net.  I am attempting to publish a sample application. I must  publish to a local directory and then use ftp to upload.
In the sites shell i am issuing the command

dotnet publish -c release

I am getting an error "the current working directory does not contain a project or solution file. "
I know I am uploading to the correct directory, but I am unsure what file extension it is looking for.
is it .sln ?

Comment: Is your shell positioned in right folder where you put your solution? It is searching for .csproj files. Check folder where your shell is at and folder where your solution is.

Comment: ok, after publishing to a folder through vs 2019 there is no .csproj file in the local publish folder, am I dealing with a publishing configuration issue ?

Comment: after publishing the project .csproj file be not present in your publish output folder. now just copy all published files to your FTP.

Comment: Of course there is not .csproj in your publish folder. You have .dll files that are your projects. Now with FTP transfer those publish files to your server, where app is hosted.

Comment: it is hosted on cloudclustrs. the tech support is less than helpful right now.

Comment: yes I have the dll files. and they are uploaded to the correct directory. This issue might be more of a tech support issue with cloud clusters i just wanted to make sure that it was not something i was doing on .net side.  Still learning asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help newbies. The problem ended up being that cloudclusters.co required you to upload your source files. Do not use .net package deployment or any compiled code. I had to stumble across this myself. Even with tech support they could not get me to that answer, and I was asking them how I should configure the publish configuration. Their answer was "publish to a local folder then upload it". Then I needed to go to their command line shell and compile the program.